# Gnome tweaks application theme does not show

Tags: gnome, gnome-tweaks

Here i install gnome tweaks but there aren't any application bar under the theme.

[Here is my image of not showing applicaion bar for changin  themes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ckhzL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are now looking for the "Legacy Applications" settings to change the "traditional" GTK3 themes for applications. These themes will not anymore work with applications that use the newer GTK4 toolkit.